# Configure durandal for multiple SPA

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, durandal

I have a site, which technically consists of a number of separate SPAs.

```
App/Admin
App/Signup
App/MainApp
```

How should I organize the App folder and the gulp build to make this into 3-4 separate files / modules that are loaded when required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had to spend a whole day getting this to work, I will answer my own question.

First, prepare a `loader` site. This would be the main site that is actually loaded that is responsible from loading all the other sites.

> **App/main.js** - Contains the requirejs setup
>
> > In this we would run          `app.setRoot('shell', 'entrance');`
>
> **App/shell.js** - contains the router config

```
return router.map([
    { route: 'Admin/*all', moduleId: "Admin/index", nav: true },
    { route: 'Signup/*all', moduleId: "Signup/index", nav: true },
    { route: '*all', moduleId: "MainApp/index", nav: true }
])
    .buildNavigationModel()
    .activate();
```

> **App/shell.html** - contains the router usage and common header/footer/loading shield

```
<div style="height: 100%" data-bind="css: { loading: isLoading }">
 <!-- ko compose: 'loading.html'--><!-- /ko -->
 <div class="header">...</div>
 <!-- ko router: {  transition:'entrance' } --><!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

> **App/*.js** - Files shared among all the SPAs
>
> **App/MainApp/index.js** - Contains the sub router for that SPA

```
define(["require", "exports", "plugins/router"], function (require, exports, router) {
    "use strict";
    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
        .makeRelative({
        moduleId: 'MainApp',
        fromParent: false //<!----- FALSE for MainApp, TRUE for other SPA
    })
        .map([
        { route: '', moduleId: "viewmodels/test", nav: true },
    ])
        .mapUnknownRoutes("viewmodels/err", 'err')
        .buildNavigationModel();
    return (function () {
        function class_1() {
            this.router = childRouter;
        }
        return class_1;
    }());
});
```

> **App/MainApp/index.html** - Uses the router, and performs any rendering of submenues or whatever. Here the bare minimum:

```
<div data-bind="router: { }"></div>
```

> **App/Admin/index.js**
>
> > Is identical to the `MainApp.js`, except for the `fromParent` set to true and `moduleId` set to the SPAs name.

This should work fine in debug mode now.

The gulp setup becomes:

> **gulpfile.js**

```
var durandal = require('gulp-durandal');

gulp.task('build', [], function () {
 return gulp.start(['build-admin', 'build-signup', 'build-mainapp', 'build-base']);
});

function buildModule(name) {
 var path = name + '/';
 return durandal({
  baseDir: 'App',
  output: name + '.js',
  minify: true,
  almond: false,
  verbose: false,
  moduleFilter: function (moduleName) {
   return moduleName.indexOf(path) > -1;
  },

  rjsConfigAdapter: function (config) {
   config.stubModules = config.exclude;
   config.exclude = ["main"];
   config.stubModules.push('text');
   return config;
  }
 })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
}

gulp.task('build-admin', [], function () {
 return buildModule('Admin');
});
gulp.task('build-signup', [], function () {
 return buildModule('Signup');
});
gulp.task('build-mainapp', [], function () {
 return buildModule('MainApp');
});
gulp.task('build-base', [], function () {
 return durandal({
  baseDir: 'App',
  output: 'main.js',
  minify: true,
  verbose: false,
  moduleFilter: function (moduleName) {
   return moduleName.indexOf('Admin/') === -1 && moduleName.indexOf('MainApp/') === -1 && moduleName.indexOf('Signup/') === -1;
  },
  rjsConfigAdapter: function (config) {
   config.stubModules = config.exclude;
   config.exclude = [];
   return config;
  }
 })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This will now result in

```
dist/main.js
dist/Admin.js
dist/MainApp.js
dist/Signup.js
```

In your `default.html` (or whatever you call it), you need to tell it how to load these files:

```
<script>window.require = {
    bundles: { 'MainApp': ['MainApp/index'],'Signup': ['Signup/index'], 'Admin': ['Admin/index'] }
};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="main" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.2.0/require.min.js"></script>
```

The reason for this being in the html files rather than the `main.js`, is that the bundles are only used for the compiled version.